# Invoking Interface method using System.Object type variable in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface, object

I have an interface `ITest` with a method `GetResult()`. I have a class Test which implements ITest and thereby defines private method GetResult().

Next I create an instance of Test in a different class. The code is as below:

```
Module NewClass
    Public Sub New()
       Dim i As ITest = New Test()

       Dim o As Object
       o = i

       Dim b As Boolean = o.GetResult()  'This line raises "MissingMemberException" Public member 'Certify' on type 'Class1' not found. '
    End Sub 
End Module
```

I have to have `Object o` referencing this as I have other code to follow which depends on o. Please help

**Edit**:

Here is the code in the calling module

Interface:

```
Public Interface ITest
    Function GetResult() As Boolean
End Interface

Class Test
    Implements ITest

    Private Function ITest_GetResult() As Boolean Implements ITest.GetResult
        Dim result As Boolean
        ......
        ......
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

**Edit 2**:

Thanks for the instant reply.

@Vlad - I am migrating existing code from VB 6 to VB.NET and hence I'm not supposed to change the access modifier of GetResult. Leaving it Private will throw InvalidCastException Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'ITest'

@Dan - Object type variable o is used in many places and hence I don't want to change that. And yes, Test implements ITest.GetMember with a different name.

Comment: Could you please provide code how is your GetResult() method declared in ITest interface.  I more interested in the result type of it.

Answer (score 3):

I have not work with VB.NET for a long time, but what you can try is:

Make GetResult() method as friend or public

If this doesn't work then try to cast your o object to ITest interface

```
(DirectCast(o, ITest)).GetResult()
```

But you still have to have your method that implements interface as friend or public.

Comment: +1 because that one line cast `(DirectCast(o, ITest)).GetResult()` seems like the best solution for Jay, given that o must remain an `Object` for some reason. But you're wrong, actually the method that implements the interface can remain Private.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to have Object o referencing
>   this as I have other code to follow
>   which depends on o.

What do you mean? Are you aware that anywhere you have code that expects an `Object`, it can accept an `ITest`? This is one of the big benefits of inheritance.

As for the `MissingMemberException`: could you provide the definitions for `ITest`, `Test`, and `Class1`? If the `Test` type implements `ITest.GetMember` using a method with a different name (this is legal in VB.NET), that could possibly explain the exception—though that doesn't appear to be precisely where the problem lies here. Seeing the relevant code from your `Test` and `Class1` classes in particular should help a good deal.

---

**Edit**: Based on your update, here's what's going on. You're mixing VB.NET's **late binding** feature with .NET's concept of **interfaces**. Both are supported in VB.NET, but they're not the same thing.

So when you have an `Object`, you can call any method on it. This will be resolved at run-time. But **it has to be a method that actually belongs to the object's type**. In the case of `Test`, there is no `GetMember` function; there is only an `ITest_GetMember` function. So to utilize late binding, you would need to call `o.ITest_GetMember` (and this method would *also* need to be public, I believe).

That said, **I strongly advise against mixing interface implementation and late binding in this way**. In fact, I would recommend against late binding *at all* in cases like this where you actually have an interface. I really see no good reason to be casting your strongly-typed `ITest` variable to one typed as `Object`; as I stated before, you can *always* use an `ITest` as an `Object` (`Object` is the *root* of the .NET type hierarchy; you can use *anything* as `Object`), but what you *can't* always do is use an `Object` as something else.

It just seems like you are sacrificing the usability of your `i` variable (in the example code you posted) for no good reason.

---

**Edit 2**: Come to think of it, are you passing `Object` references `ByRef`? If so, I suppose that could be a legitimate reason (though I'm skeptical that you'd have good reasons for doing that).

If that's the case, you'll just need to cast your `Object` back to an `ITest` in order to use the members of `ITest`. (See, since you already *have* an `ITest` variable in `i`, this is why I keep questioning your upcast to `Object`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can actually call the interface without having to typecast it IF you do not have Option Strict set to on, however, you will get the error you get with option strict set to on.

But then again, what is the correct way of doing this with Option Strict set to on?

**EDIT**
I got the answer, which applies to my scenario and, to a larger extent, the question above. The only difference from my scenario is that the Interface is implemented in a satelite class (and therefore loaded as an assembly)
So here goes the code solution that would apply to the question above IF the interface is implemented in an assembly that is loaded at runtime.

```
For Each x In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    Dim myType = (From t In x.GetTypes() Where t.IsClass And t.GetInterface("ITest") IsNot Nothing Select t).FirstOrDefault
    'you can add other criteria inside the linq expression above to match, e.g the assembly version and / or the assembly string (which contains assembly's version)
    If myType IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim obj = Assembly.GetAssembly(myType).CreateInstance(myType.FullName)
        Dim result As Boolean = CType(myType.InvokeMember("ITest_GetResult", BindingFlags.Default Or BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, obj, Nothing), Boolean)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of "boxing and unboxing" (or lack of unboxing). I can't remember any specific resource that I would recommend, but I would go read a few blogs that go in detail about the plumbing behind casting things to and back from the Object type. Basically since you're using late binding the VB ide/compiler will convert your code into code that uses reflection against that instance's type, which is Test. Refer to the code below for clarification:

```
Dim o As Object
o = i '<-- right here is "boxing". its "boxed" up and can be treated 
''as an "Object" object. This allows it to be treated [covariantly][1]

'' What you typed: 
Dim b As Boolean = o.GetResult() '<--right here it needs to be unboxed 
''in order for the compiler to map the interface implementation. What 
''happens instead is shown below.

'' What compiled: (after converted back to vb code from IL)
'' .....keep in mind, o.GetType() returns the same type as 
''GetType(Test), NOT GetType(ITest)
Dim b As Boolean = o.GetType().InvokeMember("GetResult", 
     BidingFlags.Instance or BidningFlags.InvokeMethod 
     Or BindingFlags, Nothing, o, New Object() {})
```

Now the actually code probably is a little different, I'm just approximating it to demonstrate what's going on. Invoking a member like that from a Type object only searches and executes declared instance members. The runtime doesn't search and try to map interface implementations (for performance, security, and a number of other reasons). I'm not sure if you have any constraints on this, but you really need to go change all that code that uses the same variable. Every method call and property get/set is being routed through reflection.